# VSTS - UWP - Multilingual App Toolkit - build task and generated language error

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have a Xamarin Forms solution. When I build the UWP platform through the `VSBuild@1` vsts task, I get the following error:

> Package.appxmanifest(13,4): error APPX1606: All languages specified in
>   the Language attribute of the Resource element in the app manifest
>   must be supported by the Windows Store. The value of the Resource
>   element is comprised of the value from the Default Language field in
>   the App Manifest Designer and a generated the list of languages based
>   on localized resources in the project. The list of Windows Store app
>   languages is available at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=223184

I'm using the [Multilingual App Toolkit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit). So far I have the following languages: de, es, fr, it, pt, zh-Hans and zh-Hant. English is the main language.

The error seems to says that one of these languages is not supported and gives a link to check. I did so and these languages are supported.

The "Resource Element" of my app manifiest is:

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="x-generate" />
</Resources>
```

And when open through the Designer, it says the default language is 'en-US".

UPDATE

- I don't use the pseudo language
- My language resources are in a separated library referenced in the UWP project

Comment: What's the result if you build the project through Visual Studio and MSbuild command on build agent machine? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share a sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: I think the "problem" is that my language resources are in a library and not directly in the UWP project.

Comment: Do you mean the issue has been solved?

Comment: No, not solved.

Comment: What's the result if you build the project through Visual Studio and MSbuild command on build agent machine? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share a sample project on the OneDrive.